# double value cant read by fscanf in c

Tags: c, scanf

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <io.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
   FILE *tfptr;
    int accno;
    double balance;
    if((tfptr=fopen("trans.dat","w"))==NULL){ //check the file trans.dat existed or not
        printf("cannot open file. \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(stdin,"%d%f",&accno,&balance);/* read from keyboard */
    fprintf(tfptr,"%d %f",accno,balance);/* write to file */
    fclose(tfptr); //close the file trans.dat
    if((tfptr=fopen("trans.dat","r"))==NULL){ //check the file trans.dat file existed or not
        printf("cannot open file. \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(tfptr,"%d%f",&accno,&balance);/* read from file  */
    fprintf(stdout,"%d %f",accno,balance);/* write to screen */
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
12  2.3
12   0.000000
--------------------------------
Process exited with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 3):

The `"%f"` format behaves differently between [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

For `scanf` (and family) `"%f"` reads into a `float` variable, not a `double`. If you want to read a `double` then you need the `"%lf"` format for `scanf`.

Comment: Although they belong to the same family, the OP is asking about `fscanf()`, not `scanf()`